# Remove class from stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, html

Is it possible with javascript to remove an entire style from the stylesheet?

Example, to remove something like this:

```
.somestyle{
    bottom: 17px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 68px;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you don't remove the class at your html tag ?

Comment: Im dynamically generating animations that run independently of one another, and with that I append different styles with different id's

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Please check [CSSStyleSheet API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet).

Comment: @Teemu yes that is possible see my answer for more.

Comment: Dynamically altering the stylesheet is going to make the behavior really difficult to reason about and debug. There's a big bag of hurt waiting for you in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [DOM StyleSheet Object Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535871%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [`removeRule(\[index\])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531195(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`deleteRule(index)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975162(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
console.log(document.styleSheets);
document.styleSheets[0].deleteRule(0);
console.log(document.styleSheets);
```

so in your case you can do something like this

```
var sheetRef =document.styleSheets[0];/*index of the sheet in the markup head el*/
for (i=0; i<sheetRef.rules.length; i++){
if (sheetRef.rules[i].selectorText==".somestyle")
   sheetRef.removeRule(i)
}
```

i hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove class from a html tag, or add a new class and override those properties in css file with "!important"  rule.

```
.newclass{
bottom: 0px !important;
position: relative !important;
right: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: That is not what I'm asking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery .`removeAttr`:

```
$(function() {
$('.somestyle').removeAttr('class');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove a class of stylesheet, no.

However, with javascript, you can define a new style that does not inherit the sheet style.

For example:

`position: inherit;`